# Error in adding a library to a project in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I wanted to add EclipseLink library to my project. For that I went to eclipse marketplace and installed eclipse link 2.5 kepler. My Eclipse IDE is luna, which comes after kepler. So, the error is probably due to difference in versions. Is there a way to be sure that this is the real reason and nothing else ? Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

**Edit:** I just tried this - Click user libraries > expand eclipselink 2.5. It shows that libraries for eclipse link are missing (all red crosses). How can that be ? I installed eclipse link in eclipse and restarted it.

**Edit:** I noticed the path on each of the errors is pointing to the older location of my workspace (I copied it to another folder and deleted the old workspace. Some files in the workspace still remain). I wonder how I will fix this.

Comment: I didn't get that error. What I did was though, (continuing from your last post) from the project facets at the bottom where it says "further configuration available" (with JPA selected) click it. You should see JPA Facet dialog. Select EclipseLink from Platform. Select User library from Type. Click "Download Library (disk icon)" on the right. You should be able to figure the rest. Is that what you did? If not, try it, and see what happens. I'm also using luna. As far as your "EDITs" not sure what's going on

Comment: @peeskillet - fixed the problem. It was not a problem with eclipse version as I had wrongly assumed initially.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at your answer. +1 btw ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet - thanks. really appreciate it. The next thing to do is find out how to configure my dynamic web project to use the persistence provider, i.e eclipse link jars which I just added in this question. The clues are there and I am looking further - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/libAndFacetForJPA.html

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add Eclipse link to my list of eclipse user libraries. Steps Eclipse > Window > Prefernces > search word = user libraries. I saw eclipse link in that list, but it had errors as shown below:

[image]

The jar names were followed by my old workspace path followed by the text : (missing).

The error was because eclipse was somehow trying to get the eclipse link libraries from the old workspace which I deleted after copying to a new folder. Some of this directory remained. This is probably because eclipse link installed in old workspace was set to be added as a system library, i.e to the boot class path and not as a user library. Not sure.

Anyway, this is how I fixed it: In the same old user libraries window remove the old, erroneous library. Then, > New > User Library Name = **EclipseLink 2.5** > ok > Add external jars > go to folder where the eclipse link library is installed/downloaded. Select each of the jars in its lib or library folder, that is `EclipseLink 2.5.0 - Kepler\eclipselink\jlib'. You might not really need all the jars, but do it for peace of mind.

Note that sometimes the `add external jars` button will be disabled/grayed out. To enable it, select or highlight the library name you initially created, i.e **EclipseLink 2.5**.

Once done adding all those jars, click ok.

[image]

Then check the box below and finish.

[image]

Finally click ok.

[image]